# How fix notifications in status bar?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a stopwatch that can show three notifications. When i update the notifications (every second), all of them are heading up in the notification bar, switching between them.

Is there any way to prevent them from moving to the top every time they are updated?

With the following code I create notifications from different services, each one with unique CHANNEL_ID and NOTIFY_ID.

```
   private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,getResources().getText(R.string.stopwatch_channel),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }

    private Notification sendNotification(){
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.stopwatch)+" · "+String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,min,secs))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stopwatch_24dp)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .build();

        return notification;
    }

    private void updateNotification() {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, sendNotification());
    }
```